# jQuery cannot select my element from id

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a div, note the `id`:

```
<div class="@ViewHelpers.StatusToCSSClassString(detail.Status) calendar-detail @String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}_detail", Model.Date)" id="@String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}_{1}_detail", Model.Date, detail.StartTime.ToString(@"h\:mm"))">
```

Which sits inside a foreach loop (Razor) for the `@detail` view objects.  The html for these divs renders like this (the id renders correctly obviously):

```
<div class="selected-regular-time calendar-detail 07-06-2015_detail" id="07-06-2015_18:00_detail">
```

This is being rendered as a partial view.  In the parent view, I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myElement = $("#07-06-2015_18:00_detail");
    console.log(myElement);
}
```

I can see in the log that the element is null, `length == 0`.

However, if I try to select this element with another method - using `closest()` from a nearby element, it actually works - and logging the element with the console shows the correct id, that is, the id that I cannot use to select the element.

Trying to solve this problem, I have:

- made sure everything is sitting in document.ready
- triple checked the id names - even copied off the generated html
- tried to select this element from another point in the code using the closest() function - this actually works as mentioned
- searched the generated html for the page and assured there are no other elements with the same id

Comment: I bet the : is getting detected as a pseudoclass. Try var myElement = $("#07-06-2015_18\\:00_detail");

Comment: That was it dman.  I got rid of the colon and it's all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in jQuery selectors with `\\`

```
$("#07-06-2015_18\\:00_detail");
```

Underscore and hyphen are ok and not considered special characters

For full details see [jQuery Selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: This was definitely the cause of my issue.  In my case, I simply got rid of the colon.

Comment: that's the most sensible thing to do

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're starting with numbers and then combining letters and underscores which will not be a valid id for JavaScript.

You might have better luck by using `document.getElementById('07-06-2015_18:00_detail')` but still it's not adviced to use these kind of combinations.

Comment: Numbers, underscores, colons and hyphens are all just fine. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id It's right in the HTML4 spec. It should start with a letter in HTML4 but most browsers don't care and in HTML5 the requirement is simply 1 or more characters and no spaces.

Comment: nothing wrong with combinations you mentioned or numbers. Scroll down this page and look at what is allowed...will blow your mind  https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: ye you're right, I've changed my answer. problem is the start with a number and then combining it with letters and underscores. I'm sure there's a more "regexp" way of declaring a valid id but this is from my experience.

Comment: no..there is no rule like that in html5. The link 2 comments up I posted came out of jQuery docs. Worth looking at

Comment: @charlietfl HTML5 is as I said, at least 1 character and no spaces. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Back in the HTML4 day, I remember my id's failing over a combination of underscores followed by a number. Perhaps it's changed. Anyway, you'll find this kind of problems for example with complex asp.net id's.

Comment: @dman2306 am aware of that...can put just about anything in a selector

Answer (score 0):

The colon in your id is causing problems as it is actually used for pseudo selectors. You'll have to escape it with backslash (actually 2 of them).

```
$('#something\\:else');
```

For your example:

```
$("#07-06-2015_18\\:00_detail");
```